# Nmcli different on Linux Mint 17 than Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-mint, nmcli

I use to connect to add a connection with nmcli on Ubuntu with

```
nmcli con add
```

It appears that those options have disappeared on the Linux Mint 17 nmcli version:

```
# nmcli con help
Usage: nmcli connection { COMMAND | help }
COMMAND := { list | status | up | down | delete }
```

My version of `nmcli` is

```
# nmcli -v
nmcli tool, version 0.9.8.8
```

I guess Linux Mint is using `wpa_supplicant` directly. I use `nmcli` instead of `wpa_supplicant` for its reliability and simplicity.

1. Why does `nmcli` on linux Mint 17 differ from `nmcli` on recent Ubuntu versions
2. Where can I find the `nmcli` features that I had with Ubuntu on Linux Mint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does `nmcli` on linux Mint 17 differ from `nmcli` on recent Ubuntu versions?

Because Linux Mint 17 use the `nmcli 0.9.8.8` version and Ubuntu 16.04 and linux mint 18 use the `1.2.2` version.

> Where can I find the nmcli features that I had with Ubuntu on Linux Mint?

You should upgrade your distro to linux mint 18 , Or you can install the latest `nmcli` and network-manager from backports on Linux mint 17